# Is it customizable how long would the metadata card display on screen?

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm developing a custom receiver app using googlecast CAF SDK, and I would like to know is there an easy way to set how long would the metadata card display on screen before fading out, I did read the official document like every single day but am not capable to figure out yet...

Any solution or suggestion is welcoming!

Answer (score 0):

This currently not customizable. Please do File feature request using Cast Issue Tracker.

https://developers.google.com/cast/support

Make sure to select filed "Type" as Feature request.

Thanks.